# Pyspark - How to assign column names to default key 'key' and its values to 'value'

Tags: python, json, pyspark

Consider below sample data -

[image]

Doing below code -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df_result1 = df_data.groupBy(col("Name").alias("Name"), col("Country").alias("Country"), col("Property").alias("Property")).agg(
    (collect_list(struct(col("No"), col("Place"))).alias("details")),
)

df_result2 = df_result1.groupBy(col("Name").alias("Name"), col("Country").alias("Country")).agg(collect_list(struct(col("Property"), col("details"))).alias("Main"))
final = df_result2.toJSON().collect()
```

Actual Output -

```
{
  "Name": "David",
  "Country": "Dubai",
  "Main": [
    {
      "Property": "House",
      "details": [
        {
          "No": "1",
          "Place": "JLT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired Output -

```
{
  "Name": "David",
  "Country": "Dubai",
  "Main": [
    {
      "Property": "House",
      "details": [
        {
          "key": "No",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "key": "Place",
          "value": "JLT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Kindly suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of structs where each struct in the array contains a key value pair where the key is the column name and the value is the actual value in the column then create a `Main` column by packing the array along with the `Property` column. Finally group the dataframe and aggregate the `Main` column with a list

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

details = F.array(*[
    F.struct(F.lit(c).alias('key'), F.col(c).alias('value')) 
    for c in ('No', 'Place')
])

df_result = df_data.groupBy('Name', "Country").agg(
    F.collect_list(
        F.struct('Property', details.alias('details'))).alias('Main')
)
```

---

```
df_result.toJSON().collect()

['{"Name":"David","Country":"Dubai","Main":[{"Property":"House","details":[{"key":"No","value":"1"},{"key":"Place","value":"JLT"}]}]}']
```

Comment: Thank you Shubham. Your solution resolved my problem!